# Is there such a thing as couchbase basket?

Tags: couchbase

I have heard only of `couchbase bucket` is there also a `basket`? I would like to have multiple apps use multiple `buckets` but for couchbase performance is there a lighter thing than a `bucket` called `basket`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never heard of a basket in Couchbase. Now that being said we strongly encourage people to add a type field to every document stored in buckets. Before having queries we would tell you to do multiple applications by prefixing all your document keys by the app prefix. Now that we have n1ql and that you can do queries based on the content, you should add a field in the doc as well.
From a security perspective you'll be mixing stuff from different app in the same bucket. We have no way to make any distinction right now between doc from one app or the other on the server side. It means your security model has to be handled on the client/application layer.